# Bulma CSS button always next to various inputs or selects

Tags: bulma

I want to have the delete button next to every select or inputs, I know is possible with:

```
<div class="field is-grouped">
  <p class="control is-expanded">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Find a repository">
  </p>
  <p class="control">
    <a class="button is-info">
      Search
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

For example, but is not enough in this case, because I have one select and one input that looks like this:

[image]

I want to have that delete button next to those elements, in the middle, like this:

[image]

And if the screen is small, that button always maintain there...

[Here](https://codepen.io/montoyaandres/pen/zymdVx) a little example.

Someone know how can do it? Thanks :D

Comment: Cuong, why are you hater? If dont want to help, only ignore it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9b4yxuL6/10/